# HTML grid has to much space between elements

Tags: html, css

I use HTML grid, and there is too much space between the form element.
this is my HTML code of the form (A little long but the grid is defined only in the form-element class) :

```
    <form id="embeddings_weights_form" class="form-settings">
        <div class="form-element">
            <label for="id_slider">General Similarity (view invariant):</label>
            <input type="range" min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" id="id_slider" value="1">
            <input type="text" class="range-output" id="general_similarity_output" readonly="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-element">
            <label for="category_slider">category:</label>
            <input type="range" min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" id="category_slider" value="0">
            <input type="text" class="range-output" id="category_output" readonly="">
            <select id="categoryQuery" class="query-form-class">
                <option value="[object" object]="">[object Object]</option>
                <option value="[object" object]="">[object Object]</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-element">
            <label for="color_slider">color:</label>
            <input type="range" min="-1" max="1" step="0.1" id="color_slider" value="0">
            <input type="text" class="range-output" id="color_output" readonly="">
            <select id="colorQuery" class="query-form-class">
                <option value="[object" object]="">[object Object]</option>
                <option value="[object" object]="">[object Object]</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My CSS for form-element:

```
.form-element{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

I tired giving the grid-template-columns different values, but it always looks bad (moving the last element to the next line and more bad output)

this is how the form looks:

[image]

This is how I would like it to look:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your grid-template-columns declaration, you give each column width of 1fr, this means all four columns will have the same with.

Try setting the third one to auto and play with the width of the inputs:

Also, added grid-gap property to give each column a bit of breathing space.

```css
.form-element {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.range-output {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

I created a working codepen [here](https://codepen.io/avcajaraville/pen/BaNxXPr).